# How is the value of this variable changing in my C code?

Tags: c

I have come across a very odd problem in C that I have never encountered before. I have narrowed it down to the following very simple snippet.

The variables are global and of type:

```
    int cpd;
    int nPart;
```

And here is the relevant code snippet which I gradually stripped down to the very minimum needed to produce the issue:

```
    printf("\ncpd1: %d\n",cpd);

    int p;
    for(p=1;p<=nPart;p++)
    {
        printf("\ncpd2: %d\n",cpd); exit(0);
    }
```

...The output I get is this:

```
cpd1: 17

cpd2: 0
```

How on earth is this possible?!
cpd has NOT been reassigned, NO functions have been called... yet it changed?
HOW?!?!

This has been driving me slowly insane for quite some time now...
... so any ideas?

thanks for your time,
Ben.

EDIT: and when I remove -02 from the makefile arguments to gcc, BOTH the print statements tell me that cpd = 0!

EDIT: Okay, I just found that a variable that is declared globally once, initialised as 4.0, and then never modified is now apparently 1.51086e-311   ... Something is very wrong somewhere...

EDIT: SOLVED!: I had an array of size 1000 that needed to be over 4000, and trying to write to this was corrupting the memory around it. Thing is, this array is NOT accessed anywhere near those print statements, it *is* accessed in the same function however, much earlier on (large function!). The weird discrepancy between print statements must be some weird artifact of using -O2, as without -O2, both prints of cpd print the corrupted version. Thank you everyone, I wouldnt have worked this out without your help!

Comment: Post something that compiles.

Comment: What you have here shouldn't have the bug you're describing.  Can you give some more information about your program?  Is it multithreaded?  What toolchain?

Comment: "cpd has NOT been reassigned, NO functions have been called... yet it changed? HOW?!?!" Should we believe your diagnosis or the symptom? It's clearly changed and your speculation (stripping down) is probably flawed somewhere. http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms

Comment: I completed your program by putting the code in a `main` function and initializing `cpd` to 17 and `nPart` to 1 as suggested by your output. My program output 17 and 17. The problem in your code is elsewhere.

Comment: if `nPart` is global then it's 0 so the loop shouldn't execute at all.

Comment: Alok: I can't post anything that compiles because it is part of a much larger program, and if I adapt what I posted into something that compiles, then the issue doesn't present itself!

Carl: No multithreading, I am using GCC and make.
The program consists of just <stdio.h> <stdlib.h> <math.h> and my own code.

Mehrdad: I did the 'stripping down' in the program itself, not in the post- ie what I posted is directly extracted from my code.

Charles: I did the same, and I got the same output, yet when this is part of the larger program, I get the issue.

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @user272491: then your problem is somewhere else.  Use a debugger, set a watchpoint on your variable, and good luck!  Compile your code with maximum warnings and that might help too.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I do assign the global variables before executing this code. nPart = 40000 and cpd = 17 at this point in the program. Alok: I shall do that now. Although I've played with it I have never really got the hang of gdb/ddd but I will have a try.

Comment: look for: if (cpd=1) or its cousin while (cpd=1) ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack frame corruption due to buffer overflow is the usual explanation for this.  Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int cpd;
  char msg[4];
  cpd = 17;
  printf("%d\n", cpd);
  strcpy(msg, "Oops");
  printf("%d\n", cpd);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
17
0
```

The "msg" string buffer is too short by one character, the string terminator overwrites the value of "cpd".

The best way to find the cause is to use the data breakpoint feature of the debugger.  Set a regular breakpoint on the function entry point.  Then find the address of the "cpd" variable and a set a byte-size data breakpoint on it.  The debugger will stop as soon as the cpd value changes.

Beware that this won't necessarily work in optimized code, the "cpd" value might be stored in a register.  Which is another possible explanation why its value is different in separate statements.

Comment: Interesting... but is there any way that this could happen without the strcpy between the print statements; just the integer declaration and start of a for-loop that I have?

Comment: +1. I Agree that a buffer overrun is usually the cause of these
"magic" errors.

Comment: Or a pointer write, effectively the same thing. Look for pointer writes to variables declared adjacent to cpd, they are the most likely, and trap in the debugger with break on value change.

Comment: +1 Ooh good one - didn't think of that.

Comment: You don't say what the execution environment is, but in systems
without virtual memory (such as on embedded systems) these things
can happen if the stack collides with the heap. Then the first
printf call could overwrite the cpd variable on the heap during
its operation.

Comment: I don't know how this fits in with the above, but when I remove -02 from the makefile arguments to gcc, BOTH the print statements tell me that cpd = 0!

Comment: Works on little-endian; not so well on big-endian machines.  You'd need a bigger number than 17 (0x12345678, perhaps), or a longer string than "Oops" to demonstrate on a SPARC or PPC machine.  It also assumes a specific (plausible) stack layout.

Comment: My cpu is an AMD Athlon II X4 630, which is x86_64 and little endian (I think). This is my best guess for an answer so far, as I've found that another variable that is used once and never modified has also changed value. Thank you for your repsonses!

Comment: @user272491 - I expanded my post with a debugging tip.

Comment: I <3 you all! I had an array of size 1000 that needed to be over 4000. Thing is, this array is NOT accessed anywhere near those print statements, it *is* accessed in the same function however, much earlier on. The weird discrepancy between print statements must be some weird artifact of using -O2, as without -O2, both prints of cpd print the corrupted version.
Thank you everyone, I wouldnt have worked this out without your help!

Comment: this is really old but i had the exact problem you shown in your post and it was driving me insane not knowing why an unrelated array keep getting its value changed. thank you, but why is the "oops" string too big by 1 character? isnt char msg specified to be 4 characters long already?

Answer (score 5):

Only possible reason I can think of is that you have another local int cpd variable declared.
As an example, I took your code and slightly modified it to add another int cpd declaration and left it uninitialised:
Note I had to set nPart = 1 so the for loop executed at least once

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cpd;
int nPart = 1;

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
 printf("\ncpd1: %d\n",cpd);
 int cpd;


    int p;

    for(p=1;p<=nPart;p++)
    {
        printf("\ncpd2: %d\n",cpd); 
  break;
 }
}
```

When I ran it, I got the following output:
cpd1: 0

cpd2: 2130567168

As expected, the global variable cpd is 0, the local cpd is uninitialised and can be pretty much any 32 bit value.

Comment: +1: I hadn't thought about shadowing.

Comment: I have scoured my program for all instances of cpd, and this is not the case. I also do set the variables to nPart = 40000 and cpd = 17 before this code is reached.

Answer (score 3):

That which is posted could not do that.  The only explanation is that something else is changing cpd, or cpd has multiple instances.

Comment: I am not a C expert, but I know enough C to know that this should be impossible, yet it definitely is happening... which is why this is so confusing.

Comment: There's no magic here.  The computer is doing *exactly* what it understands.  The goal is to find where you've led it astray.

Answer (score 3):

```
int main() {
    int cpd = 13;
    int nPart = 17;

    printf("\ncpd1: %d\n",cpd);

    int p;

    for(p=1;p<=nPart;p++) {
            printf("\ncpd2: %d\n",cpd);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

This compiles and runs with expected output for me. Have I incorrectly reproduced your example, or is the lack of a closing brace on the end of your for loop (and inclusion of subsequent `exit(0)` purposeful?

Edit: assume proper includes.

Comment: That's not the same as having the cpd/nPart global - ie. outside the main

Comment: OP says `cpd` and `nPart` are global.

Comment: Same for me. I tried reproducing this in a stand-alone problem, and the issue doesnt occur. I didn't bother including beyond the brace, because with the exit(0); there it is irrelevant. A closing brace does exist, and I've tried removing everything else in the loop. The issue still occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to post a complete, minimal, compilable program.  For example, the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cpd = 17;
int nPart = 10;

int main(void)
{
    int p;

    printf("\ncpd1: %d\n",cpd);

    for(p=1;p<=nPart;p++)
    {
        printf("\ncpd2: %d\n",cpd); exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

prints 17 twice.

Note:

- `nPart` is initialized to >= 1, otherwise the loop doesn't execute even once.
- I included `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` for `printf()` and `exit()` respectively.
- I left the `exit(0);` call inside the loop—not sure why you have it there since that means the loop will execute at most once.

Comment: I made this same program, and there is indeed not an issue. The exit(0) was there to help me narrow down the problem, it is not an intended function of the code! Between 2 print statements there is the code:
 "int p;

    for(p=1;p<=nPart;p++) {" and the problem occurs. I just dont see how this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

If the minimal code snippet you posted does indeed reproduce the problem, then the only explanation here is that your compiler is hopelessly broken and generates meaningless broken code.

However, I strongly suspect that the snippet you posted is not really complete (it is obviously non-compilable) and the problem lies somewhere in the code you omitted.

Comment: The snippet is copied exactly as it appears in my code. There indeed is a lot of extra code, but not between those two print statements- that is really all there is. My compiler is gcc from the ubuntu repositories (or does it even come preinstalled?), so I doubt that that is the problem too.

Comment: Well, then the most likely explanation is either someone changing your `cpd` or there's another local `cpd` declared between the prints.

Answer (score -1):

An unintialized variable can have any value, typically in debug build it will be set to zero, but you can't rely on this.

Comment: Globals have `static` storage class by default. I guess those are auto initialized.

Comment: But shouldn't the same value be printed both times anyway?

Comment: The memory that is dedicated to global variables is set to only 0 bits

Comment: @IVlad: we can't tell. `nPart` is 0 so only one `printf()` should have happened.

Comment: +1 for @anthares and @Mehrdad.  Globals are automatically initialized to zero.

Comment: The variables are definitely calculated and assigned before this code snippet is executed. I have confirmed this.

The variables are global.

Comment: @IVlad: No, it shouldn't. At least in general case. Uninitialized variables are not guaranteed to hold a stable value (this actually is sometimes observed in practice). In this case the variables are global though, so they are guaranteed to be initialized.

Comment: @anthares: Memory for global/satic variables is not set to 0 bits. Instead, the variables are guaranteed to be properly zero-initialized. If on some platform null-pointer of some type is physically represented by 0xFFFFAAAA pattern, then the corresponding global/static pointer variables are automatically set to 0xFFFFAAAA pattern.